# How can I modify Container App Environment customerId?

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I have wrongly deleted the Log Analytics Workspace and moved the Container App Environment to a new group. After that I found out my Container App Environment had the wrong customerId.

```json
      "appLogsConfiguration": {
        "destination": "log-analytics",
        "logAnalyticsConfiguration": {
          "customerId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      },
```

I tried to change that using the workspace-id using the create command below, but it didn't change. I suppose that workspaceid and customerId are the same, since I checked both.

```bash
az containerapp env create \                                                                                  
  --name samenameasbefore \
  --resource-group newgroup\
  --logs-workspace-id newid \
  --logs-workspace-key newsecret \
  --location westeurope
```

Is there any documented or undocumented way to change the customerId/workspaceid of a Container App Environment?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, the CAE workspace ID can't be changed. In order to use a specific workspace with a container app you'll need to redeploy it in a CAE that was created with the specific workspace you want to use. Currently there's no CLI command or workaround that would allow for a workspace switch on CAE.